# Bash: truncate or crop part of binary file or stdin on CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, binary-files, crop

If I have a binary file, or some command with a raw binary output, and I'm looking for a shell (bash) command to crop a specific part of data i.e. with given start and length or end offset in bytes.

For example, suppose `file.bin` contains `abcdefghijk`, I would do something like:

`cat file.bin | crop 5 3`

To indicate I want to keep only the portion from offset 5 with length 3, so this example would output `fgh`.

I know there is the `cut` command but it works on text content and processes the input line by line. In my case I'm typically dealing with binary data so there is no concept of lines. I simply want to specify the portion to be cropped in bytes.

Is there a binary alternative to `cut`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POSIX `tail`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html) with `-c` can handle arbitrary data. Unfortunately [POSIX `head`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) cannot. When limited to POSIX, you need [`dd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html); either like this:

```
<file.bin tail -c +6 | dd bs=1 count=3 2>/dev/null
```

Or like this:

```
<file.bin dd bs=1 skip=5 count=3 2>/dev/null
```

`bs=1` may be sub-optimal, but even if your `skip=` and `count=` can be recalculated to a greater `bs=`, [with POSIX `dd` only `bs=1` is right for you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618).

GNU `dd` supports `iflag=fullblock` that may help in case of greater `bs=`. In your case with GNU `dd` a better option is `iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes`:

```
<file.bin dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes skip=5 count=3 2>/dev/null
```

The above command uses the default `bs=512` and it works despite the fact neither 5 nor 3 are multiples of 512. The command should work with any sane `bs=`.

*If* your `head` supports `-c` to count bytes then it most likely does not wait for a full line when reading in this mode. This leads to the following method:

```
<file.bin tail -c +6 | head -c 3
```

---

There may be other solutions. Note if `command1` prints the first 5 bytes from its input and `command2` prints the first 3 bytes of its input then

```
{ command1 >/dev/null; command2; } <file.bin
```

may *or may not* work. *In general* `command1` may read *more* than 5 bytes (and still print 5 to its stdout), so when `command2` starts reading, the pointer may be in the wrong place. The commands I gave you do not follow this potentially flawed pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`dd` will do that. If you need a granularity of one byte, you have to set the block size to 1:

`cat file.bin | dd bs=1 skip=5 count=3`

Comment: "If you need a granularity of one byte, you have to set the block size to 1" – In general [your always need `bs=1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618); or `iflag=fullblock`, if supported. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17295/108618). Example mishap: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32988/108618).